# How to check a SQL Server CE database for indexes?

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-ce

Is there a way to list all SQL Server CE database table indexes, or at least for individual tables?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> -- Retrieves information about the indexes contained in the database.
>   SELECT * FROM
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES
>
> -- Retrieves all the Tables in the database including the System tables.
>   SELECT * FROM
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

[Arjuna Chiththananda - Retrieving Schema Information of SQL CE Database](http://arjunachith.blogspot.com/2007/08/retrieving-schema-information-of-sql-ce.html)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Arjuna!  you pointed me in the right direction.....  The following works.

```
SELECT 'Y' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES
where table_name = 'PP_JOB_TICKET_LIVE'
```

and index_name = 'PP_JOB_TICKET_LIVE_PK'

Thanks so much for your time.