# How do I obtain information about a nullable foreign key from Information_Schema views?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, metadata, nullable

I'm using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views in Sql Server 2005 & 2008 to obtain metadata for a database:

```
SELECT
    PK.TABLE_NAME as 'PK_TABLE_NAME',
    FK.TABLE_NAME as 'FK_TABLE_NAME',
    C.CONSTRAINT_NAME as 'CONSTRAINT_NAME'
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE
    FK.TABLE_NAME = 'Table_Name'
```

However, if I have a nullable foreign key on the table it is not included in my results because there is no matching entry for the "UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME" column.

I'm struggling to work out how to obtain information about nullable foreign keys (specifically, the name of the referenced table and column) using views in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema.  Apparently indexes aren't part of the standard, and hence [aren't included in the views](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=30841740&threadid=30841738).

*Does anyone know how I might alter my query to obtain information about nullable foreign keys?*

### Edit

As an aside, it would appear that [SQL Server Compact Edition has an INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619168/how-to-check-a-sqlce-database-for-indexes) - why does CE get this useful information?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a look and it's not the nullable FKs, but where the FK points to a unique index rather than a unique constraint/primary key it look like to me.

Even though both are implemented as indexes, a unique index does not appear in TABLE_CONSTRAINTS

There is no "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES".

So, the option would be to use the "sys" views...

Edit: using sys.indexes for the missing bit. And I don't know why SQL CE has the view...

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(PK.TABLE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME(I.[object_id])) as 'PK_TABLE_NAME',
    FK.TABLE_NAME as 'FK_TABLE_NAME',
    C.CONSTRAINT_NAME as 'CONSTRAINT_NAME'
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
    JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    LEFT JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    LEFT JOIN
    sys.indexes I ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = I.[name]
```

Comment: Hmm, it's as I suspected then.  Unfortunately the "sys" views are far more impenetrably laid-out.  More head-scratching ahead - thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

jusy look at the source code for **sp_helpconstraint**

In management Studio, go into:

```
  Databases  
    System Databases  
      master  
        Programmability  
          Stored Procedures  
            System Stored Procedures  
              sp_helpconstraint
```

You can see exactly hos Microsoft does it.  There are may other system stored procedures that you can look into that will "show" you how to get table meta data....